How to deal with -Wcast-qual when casting const char* to char*
I was wanting to replicate a function similar to strtod or strtol for my library (Targeting C99 and later). With const char* str being the input string, and char** end_str returning a pointer to the first invalid character.
// Wanting to replicate these functions
double strtod(const char* str, char** end_str);
long strtol(const char* str, char** end_str, int base);

int stringTo_int(const char* str, char** end_str) {
    int num = 0;
    while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
        num *= 10;
        num += *str - '0';
        str++;
    }
    if (end_str != NULL) { *end_str = str; } // -Wdiscarded-qualifiers
    if (end_str != NULL) { *end_str = (char*)str; } // -Wcast-qual
    return num;
}

However, *end_str = (char*)str gives a -Wcast-qual warning since it is removing const. I get this warning in both C99 and C23 in both gcc and clang (-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wcast-qual). One fix is to change end_str to be const char** end_str, but this prevents a non-const char** from being passed into end_str.
int stringTo_int(const char* str, const char** end_str);
int main(void) {
    char* text = "123abc";
    char* text_end = NULL;
    // warning/error from &text_end not being const char**
    int result = stringTo_int(text, &text_end);
    return 0;
}

It is possible to suppress the warning in gcc and clang by using pragma's, but this might not work on every compiler.
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual"
    if (end_str != NULL) { *end_str = (char*)str; }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

What is the proper way to deal with the -Wcast-qual warning?

I think, the suppressing this particular warning with pragma is the only way. After all, you add -Wcast-qual into command line, so you must want to see warnings about such casts. So I would say, either discard cast-qual completely, or add a pragma brackets around the casts you know are safe.

@EricPostpischil to clarify, I meant that it forces char* text_end to be const char* text_end when changing char** end_str to const char** end_str. I will edit my post to be more clear

@Vortex2728182818 do not assign - memcpy instead.

Do you actually plan to modify a const string using the returned non-const pointer? If not, make them both const.

@JohnBayko: As OP states, making them both const means the caller cannot pass a pointer to a non-const string. This is apparently something they want, and it is a common desire in similar routines: We want to be able to pass any string, const or non-const, to a routine. The routine will not modify the string so it is happy to have a const char * parameter.  But we also want the routine to return (via return value or pointed-to pointer) a pointer to some place in the string. This cannot properly be done in C; it is a known deficiency mentioned in the  standard,…

… stemming in part from the fact that const was added to the language late in its development.

@EricPostpischil Since C can't template like C++, best might be to explicitly do what C++ does implicitly, and have two functions, one const and one not. Difference is the non-const version can call the const version with a const end_str, and convert that to the non-const parameter for return  using ptrdiff as you described below.

I do not think that you should replicate them as they are not const correct.
But if you want to replicate them exactly as they are you can use memcpy instead of the assignment,
int stringTo_int(const char* str, char** end_str) {
    int num = 0;
    while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
        num *= 10;
        num += *str - '0';
        str++;
    }

    if (end_str != NULL) 
    { 
        memcpy(end_str, &str, sizeof(*end_str)); 
    }
    return num;
}

It will not depend on compiler-specific pragmas. Also, memcpy will not be called as modern compilers know this function very well  https://godbolt.org/z/bdq15ndof

One solution is to change the routine to provide an offset instead of a pointer:
int stringTo_int(const char * const str, ptrdiff_t *end)
{
    const char *p = str;
    int num = 0;
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        num *= 10;
        num += *p - '0';
        p++;
    }
    if (*end) *end = p - str;
    return num;
}

Then the caller would change:
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *text = "123abc";
    ptrdiff_t end;
    int result = stringTo_int(text, &end);
    char *end_text = text + end;
}

It could also be:
int stringTo_int(const char * const str, ptrdiff_t *end)
{
    ptrdiff_t i;
    int num = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'; ++i)
        num = 10*num + (str[i] - '0');
    if (*end) *end = i;
    return num;
}


I think he wants to relicate existing functions.

@0___________: Certainly they wish to produce function similar to the stated functions. That function can be provided without slavishly copying the API. It actually cannot be a copy, as their function returns int while the others do not. So  we know the API can be changed.

It looks to me like an school exercise.

The warning is there for a reason - you cannot use non-compatible pointer types interchangeably nor can you "cast away const". Either of that is undefined behavior no matter C compiler and nothing which can be solved by disabling warnings or casting. That's just hiding the problem and pretending that it doesn't exist, rather than solving it.
The modern solution is to do as C23 did with "QChar", a fictional type used just to cover the case where the caller may or may not have a const string.
Make two different functions - they could be wrappers and otherwise identical, but with different interfaces:
int string_to_int_const (const char* str, const char** end_str);
int string_to_int_rw (char* str, char** end_str);

Still you pretend that the function is named string_to_int. When called, the caller actually invokes a macro:
#define string_to_int(str, end)               \
  _Generic((str),                             \
           const char*: string_to_int_const,  \
           char*:       string_to_int_rw      \
          ) (str, end)

And now the appropriate function will be called depending on what qualifiers the pointer/array on the caller side had. As a bonus you also get an error message if the wrong type was passed.

(Please note that _Generic as per C17 makes no difference between for example const int and int but it does make a difference in case of "qualified-pointer-to-type" and "pointer-to-type".)
